# aws command not found in jenkins pipeline mac m1

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

I try to Run job jenkins pipeline ( Docker image push to AWS ECR ) by use aws command in jenkins but output tell me "aws: not found" ... I install plugin CloudBees AWS Credentials Plugin and  other plugin in AWS but it's not work.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

```
 stage('Push Image Into AWS ECR') {
            steps {
                script{
                        echo """Push Image Into AWS ECR... ${image_name}:${image_version}"""
                        withCredentials([[
                            $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                            credentialsId: 'aws-jenkins-demo',
                            accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                            secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {

                            // some block
                            sh 'aws --version'
                        }
                   }
              }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to install the aws command line utility on the jenkins node executing the pipeline. This is not done with the CloudBees plugin.

You can use the Jenkins Tool installation to do that, or install it any other way that fits your environment.